# Is it a necessary trade-off that using smart pointers requires my class to be publicly instantiable?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, abstract-class, smart-pointers

I have a base product class with a few private members and a public getter that derived classes inherit.  I would like to disqualify instantiation, since the class is intended for use with an abstract factory.  I thought protected con/destructors might work, however, this breaks my smart pointers.  Friending seems like a useful disaster.  Is there a well-known solution to this, or should I resign myself to the fact that any client who has the factory injected must also know enough to instantiate the base product?

```
class Product
{
private:
    char type_name;
    char size_name;
public:
    Product(char, char);
    virtual ~Product() {}
    void Print();
};
```

Comment: An abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post.

Comment: @Eljay I hated your reply at first.  But now I think you are right on.  If I mean for it to be  abstract, I need to make it abstract.  Perhaps I will move the Print() function out to a Visitor or something.  Thanks for being...direct.

Answer (score 2):

Your static member function, or friend function, which is the factory should have no problem with calling protected constructors and returning a smart pointer. Generally plan to return a `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>` which can be converted into a `std::shared_ptr` if the caller wants that instead.

Make the virtual destructor public.

Update: Don't bother making the factory a friend. You only need to prevent the construction of the base and intermediate classes. Make them effectively hidden and private by hiding the implementation classes in their own source file. Or an anonymous namespace I suppose.

Here have some code of how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

// ITest is the only class any other code file should ever see.
class ITest {
protected:
  ITest() = default;

public:
  virtual ~ITest() = 0;

  virtual int getX() const = 0;
  virtual int getY() const = 0;
};

// Destructors must always have an implementation even if they are pure virtual.
ITest::~ITest() {}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ITest &x) {
  return os << '[' << x.getX() << ',' << x.getY() << ']';
}

// Declaration of constructTest factory function.
// Its definition should be hidden in a cpp file.
std::unique_ptr<ITest> constructTest(int x);

// The main function does not need to know anything except the ITest interface
// class and the constructTest function declaration.
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int val = 0;
  if (argc > 1)
    val = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  auto p = constructTest(val);

  std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}

// These classes should be defined in a private header file or in a cpp file.
// Should not be visible to any other code. It has no business knowing.
// Hiding all of this implementation is sort of the point of abstract interface
// classes and factory function declarations.
class TestBase : public ITest {
private:
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;

protected:
  TestBase(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x(x), y(y){};

public:
  int getX() const override { return x; }
  int getY() const override { return y; }
};

class TestA final : public TestBase {
public:
  TestA() = default;
};

class TestB final : public TestBase {
public:
  TestB(int x, int y) : TestBase(x, y) {}

  int getX() const override { return -TestBase::getX(); }
};

std::unique_ptr<ITest> constructTest(int x) {
  // make_unique is c++14.
  // For C++11 use std::unique_ptr<ITest>(new TestB(x, x)
  if (x) {
    return std::make_unique<TestB>(x, x);
    // return std::unique_ptr<ITest>(new TestB(x, x));
  }
  return std::make_unique<TestA>();
}
```

Comment: Please offer a modified version of the above code to detail your answer.

Comment: @DanielLee I updated my answer a lot. And added some code. Not related to your particular problem because you really have no detail other than "Its some kind of Product thing." Take it for inspriation.

Comment: Thank you for your effort.  However, I am not yet high enough level to cast this spell. =)

Answer (score 2):

Use a token key.

```
private:
  Product(char, char);
  struct key_t{explicit key_t(int){}};
  static key_t key(){return key_t(0);}
public:
  Product(key_t, char a, char b):Product(a,b){}
  static std::shared_ptr<Product> make_shared(char a, char b){ return std::make_shared<Product>(key(),a,b); }
```

anyone with a `Product::key_t`  can construct a `Product` without being a friend.  And without the key, you cannot.

This lets `Product` pass creation-rights as a value.

Smart pointers with configurable destroy code can use similar techniques.  But I'd just make the destructor public.

Comment: Hey!  That's clever!  Thanks!

Comment: My destructor is public for that reason.  It broke the shared_ptr when I made it protected.

Comment: @daniel shared ptr supports custom destroyers same with unique ptr.

Comment: Why does `key_t` take an `int` in its constructor?

Comment: @0x499 It needs to be explicit so you have to name it; otherwise a `{}` would sometimes pick the lock.  A one arguement explicit int constructor prevents a few loopholes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to make the destructor a pure virtual AND to implement it with an empty body.  That empty implementation is where I got tripped up.  Print() doesn't need to be static.

### Product.hpp

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Product {
public:
    virtual ~Product() = 0;
    void Print();
protected:
    char type_name{};
    char size_name{};
private:
};
```

### Product.cpp

```cpp
#include "Product.hpp"

Product::~Product() {}

void Product::Print() {
    //Print p
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. Making the destructor pure virtual achieves the same effect and doesn't add an unnecessary dummy function.

Comment: Making my destuctor pure virtual introduces this error:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Product::~Product(void)" (??1Product@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall ProductALarge::~ProductALarge(void)" (??1ProductALarge@@UAE@XZ) DesignPatterns C:\Users\danie\source\repos\DesignPatterns\AbstractFactory.obj 1

Comment: Error at:  // FUNCTION TEMPLATE make_unique
template <class _Ty, class... _Types, enable_if_t<!is_array_v<_Ty>, int> = 0>
_NODISCARD unique_ptr<_Ty> make_unique(_Types&&... _Args) { // make a unique_ptr
    return unique_ptr<_Ty>(new _Ty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...));
}

Comment: Fixed it for you

Comment: That said though, you should re-think whether or not Print should be a part of the class at all; maybe a non-member, non-friend free function inside a namespace that takes a product as an argument would work better.

Comment: First:  You are my hero.  Second:  Yeah, I know Print() probably doesn't belong here.  But the function does have specific knowledge of the protected members I am printing and it's just a debug while I'm grinding through GOF.  Thanks again!